# How to show calculation history in javascript when making a html-based calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make an HTML-based calculator and it also displays the previous calculation history but I was confused about how to do it.
How to store the previous calculation results as a string a something else that can be used later on?
Hi, I was trying to make an HTML-based calculator and it also displays the previous calculation history but I was confused about how to do it.
How to store the previous calculation results as a string a something else that can be used later on?

```
<html> 
   <head> 
      <script> 
         //function that display value 
         function dis(val) 
         { 
             document.getElementById("result").value+=val 
         } 

         //function that evaluates the digit and return result 
         function solve() 
         { 
             let x = document.getElementById("result").value 
             let y = eval(x) 
             document.getElementById("result").value = y 
         } 

         //function that clear the display 
         function clr() 
         { 
             document.getElementById("result").value = "" 
         } 
      </script> 
      <!-- for styling -->
      <style> 
         .title{ 
         margin-bottom: 10px; 
         text-align:center; 
         width: 175px; 
         color:grey; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         } 

         input[type="button"] 
         { 
         background-color:grey; 
         color: black; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         width:100% 
         } 

         input[type="text"] 
         { 
         background-color:white; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         width:100% 
         } 
      </style> 
   </head> 
   <!-- create table -->
   <body> 
      <div class = title >ITP2 Calculator</div> 
      <table border="1"> 
         <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="result"/></td> 
            <!-- clr() function will call clr to clear all value -->
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <!-- create button and assign value to each button -->
            <!-- dis("1") will call function dis to display value -->
            <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"/> </td>  
            <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="Clr" onclick="clr()"/> </td>
            <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"/> </td>   
         </tr> 
      </table> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

Display history examples:
2+3=5
3+5=8

Comment: Please rewrite the last sentence of your question. As it is it doesn't quite make sense. Also narrow your question to something very specific that you can't solve. If you simply ask "how do I do this" the question may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function, that will be saving data to some variable, and then just call this function every time you want to add something to the history. Here is an example:

```
let history = '';

function dis(val) {
    // your code...

    addToHistory(val);
}

function solve() {
    // your code...

    addToHistory('=' + y);
}

function clr() {
    // your code...

    addToHistory(' ');
}

function addToHistory(value) {
    history += value;
    document.getElementById('history').innerText = history;
}
```

You can take a look at how it's working here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y9qfwxn/2/)